# ways to implement desktop application with maps

Tags: java, swing, google-maps, maps, desktop-application

i need to implement a desktop application (possibly with Java Swing) in which i can implement maps (not only Google maps but also other services) in two ways: online and offline. Online means the application calls API services by internet, while offline means that i have maps services saved locally and i can request for them also without an internet connection..
Specifically, my application has to draw a polygon on the map (with the API) and do some computations on the background..
Given this, what services can i use to implement at least one way (online or offline) or both? Thanks so much

Comment: INterms of Java libs Start by investigating the GeoTools API and maybe the related GeoServer.

Answer (score 1):

Initially, google maps only allowed online use of it's API. Any attempt to save maps for use offline was an offence.

I know that the current google maps app (Android / IOS) supports storing maps offline but I don't think this is open to third parties such as yourself. As with everything google, they want your data so they won't let you use the maps offline since they can't see how it's being used.

I've seen many offline mapping applications based on [open street map](http://www.openstreetmap.org/about). These maps are open source and free to use as you please (online / offline).